# Rx: Combine ThrottleFirst and Sample operators

Tags: rx-java

Given a source observable S, how can I ask RxJava / Rx to produce observable D, that:

1. Emits first item from S without any delay
2. Waits at least T seconds after emitting every item and before emitting next item L, where L is the last item emitted by S during the waiting period
3. Emits the next item immediately after it appers in S, if S didn't produce any item during the waiting period T (from the point #2)

Marble diagram:

[image]

I thought to use:

- Sample operator, but it does not satisfy the requirement #3.
- Debounce operator, but it also does not satisfy the requirement #3.
- ThrottleFirst operator but it does not satisfy the requirement #2, because it does not remember L (while Sample does that).

I would prefer the most simple answer, that utilises standard operators (if it is possible).

Comment: Could you draw a marble diagram that demonstrates how the operator should act on the various timing of source events? If S produced an item during time T and this item is emitted right after T, what should happen to the immediate subsequent item from S?

Comment: I will draw it later today. Answering the second question: the immediate subsequent item should be delayed until T elapsed one more time, or it should be ignored, if another item from S was emitted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If one is limited to standard operators only, this could be achieved by using `publish` and switching between two collection modes: direct, and buffer with time. In the latter mode, if the buffer turns out to be empty, switch back to the direct mode:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.*;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.TestScheduler;

public class ThrottleSampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        TestScheduler tsch = new TestScheduler();

        Flowable.fromArray(
                100,                // should emit 100 at T=100
                110, 120, 130, 150, // should emit 150 at T=200 
                250, 260,           // should emit 260 at T=300
                400                 // should emit 400 at T=400
        )
        .flatMap(v -> Flowable.timer(v, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, tsch).map(w -> v))
        .compose(throttleFirstSample(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, tsch))
        .subscribe(v -> 
            System.out.println(v + " at T=" + tsch.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        );

        tsch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    static final Exception RESTART_INDICATOR = new Exception();

    static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, T> throttleFirstSample(
            long time, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
        return f ->
            f
            .publish(g ->
                g
                .take(1)
                .concatWith(
                    g
                    .buffer(time, unit, scheduler)
                    .map(v -> {
                        if (v.isEmpty()) {
                            throw RESTART_INDICATOR;
                        }
                        return v.get(v.size() - 1);
                    })
                )
                .retry(e -> e == RESTART_INDICATOR)
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The alternative is to have a custom operator:

```java
@Test
public void testObservable() {
    TestScheduler tsch = new TestScheduler();

    Observable.fromArray(
            100,                // should emit 100 at T=100
            110, 120, 130, 150, // should emit 150 at T=200 
            250, 260,           // should emit 260 at T=300
            400                 // should emit 400 at T=400
    )
    .flatMap(v -> Observable.timer(v, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, tsch).map(w -> v))
    .compose(throttleFirstSampleObservable(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, tsch))
    .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v + " at T=" + tsch.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

    tsch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> throttleFirstSampleObservable(
        long time, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
    return f -> new Observable<T>() {
        @Override
        protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer) {
            f.subscribe(new ThrottleFirstSampleObserver<T>(
                observer, time, unit, scheduler.createWorker()));
        }
    };
}

static final class ThrottleFirstSampleObserver<T> 
extends AtomicInteger
implements Observer<T>, Disposable, Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 205628968660185683L;

    static final Object TIMEOUT = new Object();

    final Observer<? super T> actual;

    final Queue<Object> queue;

    final Worker worker;

    final long time;

    final TimeUnit unit;

    Disposable upstream;

    boolean latestMode;

    T latest;

    volatile boolean done;
    Throwable error;

    volatile boolean disposed;

    ThrottleFirstSampleObserver(Observer<? super T> actual, 
            long time, TimeUnit unit, Worker worker) {
        this.actual = actual;
        this.time = time;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.worker = worker;
        this.queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        upstream = d;
        actual.onSubscribe(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T t) {
        queue.offer(t);
        drain();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        error = e;
        done = true;
        drain();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        done = true;
        drain();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDisposed() {
        return upstream.isDisposed();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        disposed = true;
        upstream.dispose();
        worker.dispose();
        if (getAndIncrement() == 0) {
            queue.clear();
            latest = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        queue.offer(TIMEOUT);
        drain();
    }

    void drain() {
        if (getAndIncrement() != 0) {
            return;
        }

        int missed = 1;
        Observer<? super T> a = actual;
        Queue<Object> q = queue;

        for (;;) {

            for (;;) {
                if (disposed) {
                    q.clear();
                    latest = null;
                    return;
                }


                boolean d = done;
                Object v = q.poll();
                boolean empty = v == null;

                if (d && empty) {
                    if (latestMode) {
                        T u = latest;
                        latest = null;
                        if (u != null) {
                            a.onNext(u);
                        }
                    }
                    Throwable ex = error;
                    if (ex != null) {
                        a.onError(ex);
                    } else {
                        a.onComplete();
                    }
                    worker.dispose();
                    return;
                }

                if (empty) {
                    break;
                }

                if (latestMode) {
                    if (v == TIMEOUT) {
                        T u = latest;
                        latest = null;
                        if (u != null) {
                            a.onNext(u);
                            worker.schedule(this, time, unit);
                        } else {
                            latestMode = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        latest = (T)v;
                    }
                } else {
                    latestMode = true;
                    a.onNext((T)v);
                    worker.schedule(this, time, unit);
                }
            }

            missed = addAndGet(-missed);
            if (missed == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good! I will wait a few days before accepting, maybe something even more elegant will appear. Is it possible to avoid throwing an exception and use something like repeatWhen instead?

Comment: You have to communicate the mode switch through some means that doesn't interfere with normal completion of the source. With repeatWhen, the handler would become more complicated as it would need to detect the main source completed but not trigger completion prematurely by itself.

Comment: What I find more elegant is a custom operator where there is no chance of race between the time windows and the source events. Updated the answer with one such operator.

Comment: So much work you did! It's probably a good candidate to include into RxJava2 library itself. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

My two cents here is that you could solve this with throttleFirst and throttleLatest and then merging them together.

```java
public class ThrottledEmitter {
    public Observable<Integer> createEmitter(Observable<Integer> source, Scheduler scheduler) {
        Observable<Integer> first = source.throttleFirst(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler);

        Observable<Integer> last = source.throttleLatest(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
                .withLatestFrom(first, (f, s) -> new Integer[]{f, s})
                .filter(array -> array[0] != array[1])
                .map(array -> array[0]);

        return first.mergeWith(last);
    }

    @Test
    public void VerifyEmitter() {
        TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        Subject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
        Observable<Integer> emitter = createEmitter(subject, testScheduler);
        TestObserver<Integer> tObserver = emitter.test();

        subject.onNext(100);
        subject.onNext(200);
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(199, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        subject.onNext(400);
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        subject.onNext(500);
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        subject.onNext(600);
        subject.onNext(700);
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        subject.onNext(800);
        subject.onNext(800);
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        tObserver.assertValueAt(0, 100);
        tObserver.assertValueAt(1, 400);
        tObserver.assertValueAt(2, 500);
        tObserver.assertValueAt(3, 600);
        tObserver.assertValueAt(4, 700);
        tObserver.assertValueAt(5, 800);
        tObserver.assertValueAt(6, 800);
        tObserver.assertValueCount(7);
    }

}
```

This will also ensure that the events emitted are unique based on identity. Same event from both streams have the same identity because the event source is the same.