# proper video streaming with rxjava

Tags: opencv, rx-java

To handle a video stream from a webcam (delivered by opencv) i am considering to use RxJava.

I am hoping to achieve the following:

- being able to control the frames per second to be delivered
- to be able to handle different inputs - e.g. a life webcam, a video or even a still picture
- being able to switch to a picture-by-picture handling under the control of a gui

I have been experimenting a bit with RxJava but i am confused about the debounce, throttleFirst and [async operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Async-Operators)

Examples like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48723331/1497139 show some code but I am missing more detailed explanation.

**Where could I find a decent example for video processing or something similar along the needs mentioned above?**

The code below does some non async logic at this time - please let me know if i could build on it:

**ImageFetcher**

```java
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.functions.Func0;
import rx.functions.Func1;

/**
 * fetcher for Images
 *
 */
public class ImageFetcher {
  // OpenCV video capture
  private VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
  private String source;
  protected int frameIndex;

  public int getFrameIndex() {
    return frameIndex;
  }

  /**
   * fetch from the given source
   * 
   * @param source
   *          - the source to fetch from
   */
  public ImageFetcher(String source) {
    this.source = source;
  }

  /**
   * try opening my source
   * 
   * @return true if successful
   */
  public boolean open() {
    boolean ret = this.capture.open(source);
    frameIndex=0;
    return ret;
  }

  /**
   * fetch an image Matrix
   * 
   * @return - the image fetched
   */
  public Mat fetch() {
    if (!this.capture.isOpened()) {
      boolean ret = this.open();
      if (!ret) {
        String msg = String.format(
            "Trying to fetch image from unopened VideoCapture and open %s failed",
            source);
        throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
      }
    }
    final Mat frame = new Mat();
    this.capture.read(frame);
    frameIndex++;
    return !frame.empty() ? frame : null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
  }

  /**
   * convert me to an observable
   * @return a Mat emitting Observable 
   */
  public Observable<Mat> toObservable() {
    // Resource creation.
    Func0<VideoCapture> resourceFactory = () -> {
      VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
      capture.open(source);
      return capture;
    };

    // Convert to observable.
    Func1<VideoCapture, Observable<Mat>> observableFactory = capture -> Observable
        .<Mat> create(subscriber -> {
          boolean hasNext = true;
          while (hasNext) {
            final Mat frame = this.fetch();
            hasNext = frame!=null && frame.rows()>0 && frame.cols()>0;
            if (hasNext) {
               String msg = String.format("->%6d:%4dx%d", frameIndex, frame.cols(), frame.rows());
               System.out.println(msg);
               subscriber.onNext(frame);
            }
          }
          subscriber.onCompleted();
        });

    // Disposal function.
    Action1<VideoCapture> dispose = VideoCapture::release;

    return Observable.using(resourceFactory, observableFactory, dispose);
  }
}
```

**ImageSubscriber**

```java
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import rx.Subscriber;

public class ImageSubscriber extends Subscriber<Mat> {

  public Throwable error;
  public int cols = 0;
  public int rows=0;
  public int frameIndex=0;
  public boolean completed = false;
  public boolean debug = false;

  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {
    completed = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {
    error = e;
  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(Mat mat) {
    cols = mat.cols();
    rows = mat.rows();
    frameIndex++;
    if (cols==0 || rows==0)
      System.err.println("invalid frame "+frameIndex);
    if (debug) {
      String msg = String.format("%6d:%4dx%d", frameIndex, cols, rows);
      System.out.println(msg);
    }
  }
};
```